# Hide console variables in Pycharm debugger variables panel

Tags: pycharm

As can be seen in the screenshot there are a lot of general variables being displayed that are irrelevant to my python script:

[image]

Note: I've already looked at this note from `JetBrains`: none of their solutions worked.  https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000754924-Disable-Scientific-mode-in-PyCharm

a.

[image]

b.

[image]

How can these variables be supressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Click on the three vertical dots:

   [image: console]
2. Click **Simplified Variables View**

Answer (score 7):

Go to File > Settings, the window pop-ups and you go to Build, Execution, Deployment > Console. Here you un-flag the option *"Show console variables by default"*.

Comment: javadba already mentionned that solution in his question and indicated it didn't work for him.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see `screenshot b'

Answer (score 1):

Try to enable *"Show Variables"* in PyCharm:

[image: click here]

Comment: The question is asking how to _filter_ / _reduce_ the number of variables shown. How is this an answer to that question?

Comment: Oh, my mistake. It was just for hiding all Variables. Almost variables that you used seems like int variables. I would encapsulate them in a dictionary, if I were you.

Answer (score -1):

These appear when doing a

```
import * from some_library
```

This is different behavior from `intellij` - where library variables would not be displayed.

It is my impression there were *no* workaround for this -short of avoiding `import *` ..